# Why do I get "does not name a type" when I access an `extern` defined variable

Tags: c++, gcc

I have a `.h` file which contains class definition and an `extern` definition of a static variable
The accompanying `.cpp` file declares and initializes this variable.

But when I try you access this variable in my `main.cpp` I get a `does not name a type` error.
What am I doing wrong?

Contents of `test.h` file:

```
#pragma once
namespace Mine {
class Test {
  ...
};
} // namespace 
extern Mine::Test* variable;
```

Contents of `test.cpp` file:

```
Mine::Test* variable = nullptr;
```

Contents of `main.cpp`:

```
#include "test.h"

variable = new Mine::Test();
```

Comment: You can't write `variable = new Test();` in global scope. Put it inside a function.

Comment: Do you have a `using namespace Mine;` somewhere before you use `Test`? If not, you need to specify it as `Mine::Test`.

Comment: @Adrian You are correct, fixed the post. But that didnt solve the problem

Comment: @Pete Becker Why not?

Answer (score 0):

As @pete-becker suggested, putting the initialization of `variable` in `main.cpp` in a function solves the problem.

But I don't understand why

[Edit] I do now, see comment below

Comment: You can't execute code outside of a function (and `main` counts as a function). When you declare/initialize a simple variable, like: `int p = 2;` (or, in your case, `Mine::Test* variable = nullptr;`), the compiler can fill in all necessary data/memory ***at compile time***. However, when you try `variable = new Mine::Test();` then that statement ***requires*** that some code actually be executed (in order to call the constructor of `Test`).

Comment: Thanks for this clarification

Comment: Every variable is initialized when it’s created. Your `variable` is initialized (with the value `nullptr`) in “test.cpp”. That `variable = new Test();` is not initialization. It’s assignment.